# Passing a functions with arguments as an argument

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I'm creating a webapp which should do multiple async functions in a loop. I've got the following:

```
function async(asyncFunction, callback) {
    console.log("Async operation is being executed.");
    setTimeout(function () {
        asyncFunction();
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }, 0);
}

setInterval(async(function () { myFunction("this argument", "and this one"); }, null), 2000);
```

As you can see I have the `myFunction` with arguments and want to use tis statement as an argument for the `async` function. Now I've searched a little and tried to solve this using a anonymous function. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It doesn't loop anymore and just kills after 1 execution.

Any statements after are being called and executed. No errors show up in the console. Please help me out.

Comment: You want to call multiple diffrent async calls to the server...I dont get why you have made so many timeouts and set intervals. Is there any good reason for that.

Comment: I added another timeout to test something, it's gone now ;)
About the other ones.. The interval is to create the loop, the timeout in the `async` function is to actual make it async (i've been told)

Comment: Also, I do use AJAX, so the calls are actually async already, but I will have multiple managers doing a call and other stuff.. and that whole process has to be async in a loop along with others.

Comment: But all ajax calls are async by default you don't have to do any thing to make it async.

Comment: It's not AJAX calls I'm going to do.. Let me edit the post, I want to make functions async, for example I could use an AJAX call, which I will do as well, but mostly other functions !

Comment: Is it probably reasonable to start using web workers? It looks like exactly what you need See more details at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers .